# Why can't I set a variable equal to a function return value in GLSL (WebGL)?

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader

I just started playing around with GLSL Sandbox (http://glsl.heroku.com), and I noticed that the code won't compile if I declare a function and try to pass its return value into a variable in the main function. This is what I have right now:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform float time;

void main( void ) {
    float color = test(); // code breaks here
    gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( color, color * 0.5, sin( color + time / 3.0 ) * 0.75 ), 1.0 );
}

float test(){return 5.0;}
```

I'm not really sure why this is happening. I'm guess it's something about fragment shaders that I'm not aware of. If anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong that would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably used to languages like JavaScript or Python, where you can access values (like functions) which were declared after the point where you're trying to use them. GLSL is modeled after C and C++, so that's not possible.

If you don't want to define `test` before `main`, then you need to at least *declare* it:

```
float test();

void main( void ) {
    float color = test(); // code breaks here
    gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( color, color * 0.5, sin( color + time / 3.0 ) * 0.75 ), 1.0 );
}

float test(){return 5.0;}
```

Comment: Derp. I should have known. Thank you!